# The dictionary does not contain required key: Pages

Tags: python-3.x, pdfnet

I am trying to convert pdf to pdf/a using **PDFNetPython3**. However I am getting following errors.
Main error message:
*The dictionary does not contain required key: Pages*

According to PDFNetPython3 docs.

```
from PDFNetPython3 import PDFNet, PDFACompliance
# ... some necessary code like temp_file_path_in (this is not null and has values of file_object)

pdf_a = PDFACompliance(True, tmp_file_path_in, None, PDFACompliance.e_Level2B, 0, 0, 10)
```

Also tried using this(got same error):

```
pdf_a = PDFACompliance(True, filename, None, PDFACompliance.e_Level2B, 0, 10)
```

I wanted to know does this Pages related to pdf page numbers or total page count. I am merging a blank pdf page with other pdf pages and converting to pdfa !

Refrence: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/python/guides/features/pdfa/convert/

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception indicates that the document you are processing does not contain any pages. Since you are merging a blank PDF, it is likely you missed the [`PDFDoc.PagePushBack(page)` call.](https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFTronSDK/dotnet/pdftron.PDF.PDFDoc.html#pdftron_PDF_PDFDoc_PagePushBack_pdftron_PDF_Page_)

If this does not help, please share your code for creating and merging the PDF.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will test it and will let you know. I did not know that  PagePushBack(Page) is also required.